# c# Deserialize XMLAttribute with additional Attributes

Tags: c#, xml, rest

I have a problem deserializing responses from a REST-Service using C#.

The Rest-Service in general returns the fields of an object as a seperate object "field" with a name and a value

```
...
<Field Name="some-objects-attribute">
    <Value>attributes-value</Value> 
</Field>
...
```

which I deserialize using a class "Field".

```
[DataContract]
public class Field
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Works great but some attributes have an additional attribute in its value-tag.

```
<Field Name="some-objects-attribute">
    <Value ReferenceValue="reference-string-value">1234</Value> 
</Field>
```

Is it possible to get the information "ReferenceValue" without creating an additional Class "Value" for the value-tags.

Many thanks

Comment: try to implement the value as  [XmlAttribute] and then take the property reference value like this field.value.referencevalue

Comment: I think it's necessary to create a wrapper struct or class to convert both the `Value` and `ReferenceValue` to a single element.  Are you interested in an answer that shows how to do it?